# How can I add AnalogClock Widget on Launcher3?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing android java Launcher...
i want add AnalogClock widget into my default_workspace.xml
how can I add widget??
[code imAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk3nC.png) [i try IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ThyU.png)

```
<favorites xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.android.launcher3">

    <!-- Hotseat -->
    <include launcher:workspace="@xml/dw_tablet_hotseat" />

    <!-- Bottom row -->

</favorites>
```

Comment: i try this code

<favorites xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto/com.android.launcher3">

    <!-- Hotseat -->
    <include launcher:workspace="@xml/dw_tablet_hotseat" />

    <!-- Bottom row -->

    <AnalogClock
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            launcher:screen="0"
            launcher:x="0"
            launcher:y="-1"
    />
    <com.android.launcher3.ClockWidget
</favorites>

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)how to ask a good question. you should include what have you trid in your question itself